# Derivation of Solow Growth Model (Solow, 1956)

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, solow

In Solow's "A Contribution to the Theory of Economic Growth" paper, how do we go from this equation

[image]

to

[image]

such that

[image]

Could you please give me a hint about that derivation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that:
$$
\dot K = s K^\alpha L_0^b e^{nbt}
$$
Rewriting the differential equation gives:
$$
K^{-\alpha} \frac{dK}{dt} = s L_0^b e^{nbt} 
$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $T$ gives:
$$
\frac{1}{b} [K^b]^T_0 = s L_0^b \frac{1}{nb}[e^{nbt}]^T_0
$$
So:
$$
K^b_T = K^b_0 - \frac{s}{n} L_0^b + \frac{s}{n} L_0^b e^{nbT}
$$
Equivalently:
$$
K_T = \left[K^b_0 - \frac{s}{n} L_0^b + \frac{s}{n} L_0^b e^{nbT}\right]^{\frac{1}{b}}
$$